# VLookup simulation: copying data from one sheet to another

Tags: performance, array, vba, excel

I tried to write a VLOOKUP in my macro but for some unknown reasons it didn't work ([see my post on StackOverFlow for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045846/vlookup-function-not-working?noredirect=1#comment75120404_44045846).

So I decided to do a macro which achieves the same result, but it takes about 20 sec to run. Any ideas on how I can improve its performance ?

What this macro is doing :

I have 2 worksheets in my workbook. Both have a column listing VINs + other info. What this macro is doing is a Vlookup from one sheet to the other one to retrieve some information when the same VIN is found.

```
Sub ReplacementVlookups()

'Delete Rows with no content
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Do
    i = i + 1
    Loop While Range("A" & i) <> ""
    Rows(i & ":" & Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Delete (xlShiftUp)
Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Columns("G:G").NumberFormat = "General"
Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Columns("H:H").NumberFormat = "General"
'Store all Lookup values in a 1D array
Dim VLookupType As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastRowSF As Integer
Dim VINArrayAllTime As Variant
Dim VINArraySF As Variant
Dim ValuesCopied As Variant
Dim ValuesPasted As Variant
LastRow = Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowSF = Worksheets("Salesforce Dump").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
VINArrayAllTime = Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
VINArraySF = Worksheets("Salesforce Dump").Range("C2:C" & LastRowSF)
For VLookupType = 1 To 3 ' I have 3 columns on which I want to apply the VLookup
    If VLookupType = 1 Then
        ValuesCopied = Worksheets("Salesforce Dump").Range("D2:D" & LastRowSF)
        ValuesPasted = Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("G2:G" & LastRow)
        'Do a VLOOKUP
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            For j = 2 To LastRowSF - 1
                If VINArrayAllTime(i - 1, 1) = VINArraySF(j - 1, 1) Then
                    ValuesPasted(i - 1, 1) = ValuesCopied(j - 1, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("G2:G" & LastRow) = ValuesPasted
    ElseIf VLookupType = 2 Then
        ValuesCopied = Worksheets("Salesforce Dump").Range("E2:E" & LastRowSF)
        ValuesPasted = Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("H2:H" & LastRow)
        'Do a VLOOKUP
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            For j = 2 To LastRowSF - 1
                If VINArrayAllTime(i - 1, 1) = VINArraySF(j - 1, 1) Then
                    ValuesPasted(i - 1, 1) = ValuesCopied(j - 1, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("H2:H" & LastRow) = ValuesPasted

    Else:
        ValuesCopied = Worksheets("Salesforce Dump").Range("F2:F" & LastRowSF)
        ValuesPasted = Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("I2:I" & LastRow)
        'Do a VLOOKUP
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            For j = 2 To LastRowSF - 1
                If VINArrayAllTime(i - 1, 1) = VINArraySF(j - 1, 1) Then
                    ValuesPasted(i - 1, 1) = ValuesCopied(j - 1, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("I2:I" & LastRow) = ValuesPasted
    End If
Next VLookupType

End Sub
```

Comment: You're already using memory arrays, so you already have most of any potential speed up there. How many rows are you typically searching?

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting challenge - improve performance of arrays

But first, to cover the basics:

- **Option Explicit** is missing - this statement fixes the most basic syntax issues
- The range references are good overall, but lengthy and repetitive

  - The only one missing is on the 6th line `Rows(...` which deletes rows from active sheet
- Indentation is inconsistent, and missing at the first level (`Sub` - `End Sub`)
- The first loop doesn't work properly, and every execution it deletes the last row with data

  - For 10 rows `i=11`, but the `.End(xlUp).Row` is **`10`**, and becomes **`Rows("11:10").Delete`**

> ```
> 'Delete Rows with no content
>  Dim i As Integer
>  i = 0
>  Do
>    i = i + 1
>  Loop While Range("A" & i) <> ""
>  Rows(i & ":" & Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Delete (xlShiftUp)
> ```

---

- In all For loops you have `For i = 2 To...` & `For j = 2 To...` then compare `i - 1 = j - 1`

  - Assigning `.Range("D2:D" & LastRowSF)` to array, first item in the array is `D2` (index 1)
- The main Sub defaults to public, but the `Public` keyword should be explicit

  - Most subs and functions should be made `Private` to modules unless they are utilities

---

On to **Performance**

I'm providing 3 versions for comparison (v1 - is your version with three For loops)

- v2 - Code cleanup and optimization (three For loops)
- v3 - Improve performance - change algorithm (one For loop)
- v4 - Arrays and a dictionary (one For loop)

---

**v2 - Code cleanup and optimization (three For loops)**

```
Public Sub VinLookUpArr1()
    Dim wsAT As Worksheet, wsSF As Worksheet, valAT As Variant, valSF As Variant
    Dim lrAT As Long, lrSF As Long, vinAT As Variant, vinSF As Variant, t As Double

    t = Timer
    Set wsAT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump")
    Set wsSF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Salesforce Dump")

    lrAT = wsAT.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lrSF = wsSF.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    vinAT = wsAT.Range("A2:A" & lrAT)
    vinSF = wsSF.Range("C2:C" & lrSF)

    wsAT.Rows(wsAT.Rows(1).End(xlDown).Row + 1 & ":" & lrAT + 1).Delete xlShiftUp
    wsSF.Rows(wsSF.Rows(1).End(xlDown).Row + 1 & ":" & lrSF + 1).Delete xlShiftUp
    wsAT.Columns("G:H").NumberFormat = "General"

    valAT = wsAT.Range("G2:G" & lrAT)
    valSF = wsSF.Range("D2:D" & lrSF)
    wsAT.Range("G2:G" & lrAT) = DoLookUpArr1(vinAT, vinSF, valAT, valSF)
    valAT = wsAT.Range("H2:H" & lrAT)
    valSF = wsSF.Range("E2:E" & lrSF)
    wsAT.Range("H2:H" & lrAT) = DoLookUpArr1(vinAT, vinSF, valAT, valSF)
    valAT = wsAT.Range("I2:I" & lrAT)
    valSF = wsSF.Range("F2:F" & lrSF)
    wsAT.Range("I2:I" & lrAT) = DoLookUpArr1(vinAT, vinSF, valAT, valSF)
    Debug.Print "lrAT: " & lrAT & "; lrSF: " & lrSF & "; Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000")
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function DoLookUpArr1(ByVal vinAT As Variant, ByVal vinSF As Variant, _
                              ByVal valAT As Variant, ByVal valSF As Variant) As Variant

    Dim rAT As Long, rSF As Long, lrSF As Long

    lrSF = UBound(valSF)
    For rAT = 1 To UBound(valAT)
        For rSF = 1 To lrSF
            If vinAT(rAT, 1) = vinSF(rSF, 1) Then
                valAT(rAT, 1) = valSF(rSF, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next rSF
    Next rAT
    DoLookUpArr1 = valAT
End Function
```

---

**v3 - Improve performance - change algorithm (one For loop)**

- This loops only once for all vLookups:

---

```
Public Sub VinLookUpArr2()
    Dim wsAT As Worksheet, wsSF As Worksheet, urAT As Variant, urSF As Variant
    Dim lrAT As Long, lrSF As Long, lcAT As Long, lcSF As Long, t As Double
    Dim rAT As Long, rSF As Long, map(1 To 2, 1 To 4) As Byte, i As Long

    t = Timer
    Set wsAT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump")
    Set wsSF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Salesforce Dump")

    map(1, 1) = 1:    map(2, 1) = 3        'A to C (VINs)
    map(1, 2) = 7:    map(2, 2) = 4        'G to D
    map(1, 3) = 8:    map(2, 3) = 5        'H to E
    map(1, 4) = 9:    map(2, 4) = 6        'I to F

    lrAT = wsAT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row              'lr = last row
    lrSF = wsSF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lcAT = wsAT.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    'lc = last col
    lcSF = wsSF.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    urAT = wsAT.Range(wsAT.Cells(1), wsAT.Cells(lrAT, lcAT))    'ur = used range
    urSF = wsSF.Range(wsSF.Cells(1), wsSF.Cells(lrSF, lcSF))

    For rAT = 2 To lrAT
        For rSF = 2 To lrSF
            If urAT(rAT, map(1, 1)) = urSF(rSF, map(2, 1)) Then
                For i = 2 To 4
                    urAT(rAT, map(1, i)) = urSF(rSF, map(2, i))
                Next
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    wsAT.Range(wsAT.Cells(1), wsAT.Cells(lrAT, lcAT)) = urAT
    Debug.Print "lrAT: " & lrAT & "; lrSF: " & lrSF & "; Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000")
End Sub
```

---

**v4 - Arrays and a dictionary (one For loop)**

- The most important improvement is gained by the **`.Exists()`** method of the dictionary

---

```
Public Sub VinLookUpDictionary()
    Dim wsAT As Worksheet, wsSF As Worksheet, urAT As Variant, urSF As Variant
    Dim lrAT As Long, lrSF As Long, lcAT As Long, lcSF As Long, t As Double
    Dim rAT As Long, rSF As Long, map(1 To 2, 1 To 4) As Byte, i As Long, d As Dictionary
    t = Timer
    Set d = New Dictionary
    Set wsAT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Time SMS Dump")
    Set wsSF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Salesforce Dump")
    map(1, 1) = 1:    map(2, 1) = 3        'A to C (VINs)
    map(1, 2) = 7:    map(2, 2) = 4        'G to D
    map(1, 3) = 8:    map(2, 3) = 5        'H to E
    map(1, 4) = 9:    map(2, 4) = 6        'I to F
    lrAT = wsAT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row              'lr = last row
    lrSF = wsSF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lcAT = wsAT.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    'lc = last col
    lcSF = wsSF.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    urAT = wsAT.Range(wsAT.Cells(1), wsAT.Cells(lrAT, lcAT))    'ur = used range
    urSF = wsSF.Range(wsSF.Cells(1), wsSF.Cells(lrSF, lcSF))
    For rSF = 2 To lrSF
        d(urSF(rSF, map(2, 1))) = vbNullString
    Next
    For rAT = 2 To lrAT
        For rSF = 2 To lrSF
            If d.Exists(urAT(rAT, map(1, 1))) Then
                For i = 2 To 4
                    urAT(rAT, map(1, i)) = urSF(rSF, map(2, i))
                Next
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    wsAT.Range(wsAT.Cells(1), wsAT.Cells(lrAT, lcAT)) = urAT
    Debug.Print "lrAT: " & lrAT & "; lrSF: " & lrSF & "; Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000")
End Sub
```

---

**Results**

```
Total Rows on sheet "All Time SMS Dump": 20,001
Total Rows on sheet "Salesforce Dump":   20,001
```

> ```
> v1 = Time: 53.469 sec (arrays - 3 loops)
> v2 = Time: 54.676 sec (arrays - 3 loops)
> v3 = Time: 20.637 sec (arrays - 1 loop)
> v4 = Time:  0.484 sec (arrays & dictionary - 1 loop)
> ```

Comment: I like the way this answer whittles down the problem.